# External Controllers - Unexpected Behaviour and Operation

Tags: external-calls

My system has Windows 10 Pro 20H2, Mathematica 11.1.1.0 and the following external controllers *plus* **Loupedeck Live**:

[image]

1- Why do the following commands work:

a)

[image]

These don't:

b)

[image]

These don't update in Dynamic:

c)

[image]

This one works for the **Joystick T.16000M** (the first device that has "X Axis" etc), although the **Slider** doesn't work as it is expected (instead of presenting its value it updates like a joystick):

d)

[image]

And this doesn't work:

e)

[image]

?

2- Why **ControllerInformation** doesn't find **Loupedeck Live**?

3- Why data from **Microsoft Hardware USB Mouse** controls (1029 controls!) is not updated in Dynamic?

4- Why except for the multimedia controls none of the keys of **Gaming Keyboard G610** are even presented, much less updated?

Answer (score 1):

1. Product ID is not the index for the controller.  i.e. `ControllerInformation[]` => "Controller Device #"
2. The Windows FrontEnd no longer supports 3DConnexions devices.
3. I assume that Loupedeck Live is not a DirectInput based device.  If it is not listed in the Input tab in dxdiag.exe, then it will not be enumerated in `ControllerInformation[]`.
4. It's not uncommon for a device's driver to advertise more controls then it actually supports.